# Is it possible for a bot to send embeds to a user outside of the guild?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like this command to be able to send an embed to users outside of the guild that the bot is in.

```
#Command to send a user their accepted outcome
@bot.command()
async def accept(ctx, *, user : discord.User):
        date = datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
        time = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        embed = Embed(title="Application Accepted",
                                    description=f"Hello *{user.display_name}*, as of `{date}`, at `{time} GMT`, your application for *__California Department of Public Safety__* is being **ACCEPTED!** Congratulations and welcome to the force, please follow the directions listed below.",
                                    color=dps)
        embed.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/935059565588930601/946165855874592878/approved-accepted.gif")
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Accepted By {ctx.author.display_name} | {ctx.guild.name}', icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
        
        fields = [("Step One", "First off, please start by joining this server via this link: https://discord.gg/RvFFkCwEw8.", False),
        ("Step Two", "Second, please request your training here: <#941513740950597717>, once you do that please wait for a ping here:<#941513740950597715>, you will have 2 weeks to complete your training before removal.", False),
        ("Step Three", "After completion of training, you're going to want to make a role request here: <#941513740749246472>, roster request here: <#941513740749246470>, and finally a ride-along request here: <#941513740749246468>. For the last and final step you're going to want to head here: <#941513740304670750> to read the SOP and recieve your uniform, loadout, and vehicle.", False)]
        
        for name, value, inline, in fields:
            embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)
        await user.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(f'✅')
```

Comment: You have to share a server with the person you are messaging. It's a discord limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that  `await create_dm()` function can be used for your question. Normally, for welcoming newcomers to your guild, uses this piece of code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild
    guildname = guild.name
    dmchannel = await member.create_dm()
    await dmchannel.send(f"welcome to {guildname}!")
```

When you use `.send`, you take parameter message from function, then specify channel and send it. During this, you provide a message. As an example:

```
await msg.channel.send("anytext")
```

However you need a channel to send a DM. To do that, you should create a DM channel  by using `create_dm()` which creates a DM channel with given user. Assign right side to `dmchannel` variable:

```
dmchannel = await user.create_dm()
```

Then send your message to user:

```
await dmchannel.send("anytext")
```

Comment: `await user.send` is a shortcut to using `create_dm` and `dm.send`. Also the question was if a bot can send DMs to a user it has no common guilds with, which is not possible as pointed out by the comment.